# Display Videos on Fedora without desktop enviorment?

Tags: fedora, display

I have Fedora ARM 23 installed on my RPI and I want to display a video on an attached screen, I wander if I can display the video without having to install gnome or other desktop environments, if it's the case, please instruct me on the required tools do so.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the below commands by booting into runlevel 3

```
echo xterm > `~/.xinitrc` 
startx
```

It will start xterm in X without any Desktop Environment. 
From this xterm, you can execute the command to play the video.

```
e.g. vlc <video_Path>
```

NOTE: Take a backup of ~/.xinitrc file, if already present.

**Also, I haven't tried this, but it should work.**

Comment: I ll try it out and let u know

Comment: You can also try `mplayer` which has different methods to output the video. Look in the manpages for `-vo` where the different supported types should be described. The `fbdev` method should work even without any X environment.

Comment: @Thomas u mean i dont have to install xterm and mplayer would work?

Comment: Yes correct. I was able to do so on a different ARM board than RaspberryPi with `mplayer`.

Comment: i figured i ll try both solutions and see what goes best, actually @SHW , it seems like i need some tools preinstalled to use your solution, can u help me out on that? I installed xterm and did  `echo xterm > ~/.xinitrc` then i tried startx but guess i need to install something else to get it working `bash: startx: command not found
`

Comment: Instead of "startx" try `xinit`

Comment: @SHW `bash: xinit: command not found`
there should be something i need to install

Comment: @Thomas i ve looked into what you saied but am getting alot of errors when i do `mplayer -vo fbdev centaur_1.mpg` are there some constraint on the video format while using this?

Comment: SO i kind of mashed up both of what u guys suggested , and i can launch a video now , however when i tried displaying a large sized one , it kind of ran slowly using the fbdev driver

Comment: Turns out mplayer is no good , it doesn t use the graphics acceleration , looking into omxplayer now